# How to check if a file is really of type wav?

Tags: java, android, wav

I am creating an Android application in xamarin, this app plays some audio files that come in `.wav` format, the origin of each file is unknown. That is, it can be from a server or from the device's storage.

As you can see in my title, I want to make sure that the file to be played is actually `.wav`.

Some solutions I know of are:

1. Check the file extension. This does not seem to be very reliable as the user could simply change the extension.
2. In the case of Android, I could use `MediaCodec` to extract key some with `MediaFormat`. But I want my solution to work on all API levels.

This is my code so far:

```
private bool IsWave(string file)
    {
      
        try
        {
            using var waveStream = new System.IO.FileStream(file, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
            var riffData = new byte[4]; waveStream.Read(riffData);

            var riffText = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(riffData);

            if (riffText.Equals("riff", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                waveStream.Position = 8;
                var wavData = new byte[4]; waveStream.Read(wavData);

                var wavetext = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(wavData);

                if (wavetext.Equals("wave", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                {
                    return true;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your approach
unless a library already did that for you

Comment: I've been reading this article, [link](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/WAVE/WAVE.html)  where it says ...  WAVE files often have information chunks that precede or follow the sound data (data chunk). Some programs (naively) assume that for PCM data, the preamble in the file header is exactly 44 bytes long (as in the table above) and that the rest of the file contains sound data. This is not a safe assumption. this affect this approach, or maybe the order of the data is always the same?

Comment: As i know, PCM is an encoding method for audio data in lossless wav files. But wav can also be encoded in other ways.

Comment: @Wendy Zang - MSFT  If I understand your comment correctly then checking if a file is .wav does not guarantee that you will get pcm data?  sorry if the question in this comment is obvious I'm new to audio encoding.

Comment: I think you are exactly right to suppose assuming data starts at byte 44 is truely dangerous.  Results can be deafening disaster if bytes by accidentally turn around when starting reading at wrong position.  It did not happen to me just by accident. Also lining is even luckily. Because the file was converted there was added header called LIST which moved the starting point to 78. Solution is just to skip thru unnecessary subchunks' sizes in loop at the same time updating the byte pointer until "data" is found and the fist data byte mark can be obtained for byte pointer.

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this differently. Why do you want to prevent the user from playing a wave that he/she thinks is a wave?

What is the worst what could happen if it does not play? It just won't play.

**I see a 3rd solution:**
I would just try to play it. When it fails (exception), display a message to the user that the file could not be played.

**Your other solutions are good:** Checking the extension can already filter out a lot of bad items. (.wave/.wav)
Checking the content (riff prefix) is also good but won't be 100% correct. You only know for sure until you (try to) play it.

Comment: I am using `AudioTrack` to play it, so I am feeding the audiotrack from a Stream, AudioTrack will play what it gives ... in the case of a file that does not contain pcm data this would give noise or other strange sounds